# JavaScript - Pontuação

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante.
Como fazer os pontos(placar) fique na posição verde e na mesma tela.
estou com problemas de na hora atualizar os pontos ele mostra na tela seguinte.
Exite algo a se fazer, estou usando o document.write('texto');

```html
<canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas>

<script>

    var tela = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var pincel = tela.getContext('2d');
 
    var raio = 10;
    var xx;
    var yy;
    var pontos = 0;
 
    function inicio()
    {
  pincel.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
  pincel.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
  pincel.fillStyle = 'green';
  pincel.fillRect(1000,600, 1200, 800);
  document.write('Pontos: ' + pontos);
        function sorteia()
        {
            xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
            yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
        }
        sorteia();
        function desenhaCirculo(xx, yy, raio, cor)
        {
            pincel.fillStyle = cor;
            pincel.beginPath();
            pincel.arc(xx, yy, raio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            pincel.fill();
        }
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 20, 'red'); // maior círculo
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 10, 'white');
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio, 'red'); // menor circulo
        function dispara(evento)
        {
            var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
            var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;
            if(x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10){
                alert('Acertou no alvo, e ganhou 50 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 50;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20)!= (x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10))
            {
                alert('Acertou mais nao no alvo, e ganhou 15 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 15;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 30 & x >= xx - 30 & y >= yy -30 & y <= yy + 30)!= (x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20))
            {
                alert('quase errou, e ganhou 5 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 5;
                inicio();
            }
        }
 tela.onclick = dispara;
    }
    inicio();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **innerHTML** ao invés de **document.write**, que no caso, reescreve todo o documento, por isto some.

Assim:

```
document.getElementById('pontos').innerHTML = 'Pontos: ' + pontos;
```

Quanto a ficar no lado verde, precisaria mudar o CSS e o HTML.

```html
<canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas>

<div id="pontos"></div>

<script>

    var tela = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var pincel = tela.getContext('2d');
 
    var raio = 10;
    var xx;
    var yy;
    var pontos = 0;
 
    function inicio()
    {
  pincel.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
  pincel.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
  pincel.fillStyle = 'green';
  pincel.fillRect(1000,600, 1200, 800);
  document.getElementById('pontos').innerHTML = 'Pontos: ' + pontos;
        function sorteia()
        {
            xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
            yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
        }
        sorteia();
        function desenhaCirculo(xx, yy, raio, cor)
        {
            pincel.fillStyle = cor;
            pincel.beginPath();
            pincel.arc(xx, yy, raio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            pincel.fill();
        }
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 20, 'red'); // maior círculo
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 10, 'white');
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio, 'red'); // menor circulo
        function dispara(evento)
        {
            var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
            var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;
            if(x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10){
                alert('Acertou no alvo, e ganhou 50 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 50;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20)!= (x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10))
            {
                alert('Acertou mais nao no alvo, e ganhou 15 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 15;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 30 & x >= xx - 30 & y >= yy -30 & y <= yy + 30)!= (x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20))
            {
                alert('quase errou, e ganhou 5 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 5;
                inicio();
            }
        }
 tela.onclick = dispara;
    }
    inicio();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta você utilizar as propriedades e método abaixo:

- `fillStyle` para definir a cor do texto (Caso contrário o texto ficará verde;
- `font` para definir o tamanho, tipo e estilo da fonte (opcional); e
- `fillText` para escrever algo na tela. Neste método você pode controlar a posição `X` e `Y` do elemento.

**Exemplo:**

```
pincel.fillStyle = "blue"
pincel.font = "bold 16px Arial";
pincel.fillText(`Pontuação: ${pontos}`, 1000, 700)
```

**Exemplo Completo:**

```html
<canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas>

<script>

    var tela = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var pincel = tela.getContext('2d');
 
    var raio = 10;
    var xx;
    var yy;
    var pontos = 0;
 
    function inicio()
    {
  pincel.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
  pincel.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
  pincel.fillStyle = 'green';
  pincel.fillRect(1000,600, 1200, 800);
  
    pincel.fillStyle = "blue"
    pincel.font = "bold 16px Arial";
    pincel.fillText(`Pontuação: ${pontos}`, 1000, 700)
    
    
        function sorteia()
        {
            xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
            yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
        }
        sorteia();
        function desenhaCirculo(xx, yy, raio, cor)
        {
            pincel.fillStyle = cor;
            pincel.beginPath();
            pincel.arc(xx, yy, raio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            pincel.fill();
        }
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 20, 'red'); // maior círculo
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 10, 'white');
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio, 'red'); // menor circulo
        function dispara(evento)
        {
            var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
            var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;
            if(x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10){
                alert('Acertou no alvo, e ganhou 50 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 50;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20)!= (x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10))
            {
                alert('Acertou mais nao no alvo, e ganhou 15 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 15;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 30 & x >= xx - 30 & y >= yy -30 & y <= yy + 30)!= (x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20))
            {
                alert('quase errou, e ganhou 5 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 5;
                inicio();
            }
        }
 tela.onclick = dispara;
    }
    inicio();
</script>
```

---

Caso você queira adicionar um texto abaixo do canvas — abaixo do elemento verde —, você poderá utilizar a propriedade `textContent` de um elemento HTML (`div`, `p`, `span` etc) e um pouco de CSS, por exemplo:

```
document.querySelector("#pontuacao")
        .textContent = `Pontuação: ${pontos}`;
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
#pontuacao {
  text-align:right;
  width: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas>

<p id="pontuacao">Pontuação: 0</p>

<script>

    const tela = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const pincel = tela.getContext('2d');
    const pontuacao = document.querySelector("#pontuacao")
 
    let raio = 10;
    let xx;
    let yy;
    let pontos = 0;
 
    function inicio()
    {
  pincel.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
  pincel.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
  pincel.fillStyle = 'green';
  pincel.fillRect(1000,600, 1200, 800);
  
    pontuacao.textContent = `Pontuação: ${pontos}`;
    
        function sorteia()
        {
            xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
            yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
        }
        sorteia();
        function desenhaCirculo(xx, yy, raio, cor)
        {
            pincel.fillStyle = cor;
            pincel.beginPath();
            pincel.arc(xx, yy, raio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            pincel.fill();
        }
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 20, 'red'); // maior círculo
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio + 10, 'white');
        desenhaCirculo(xx,yy, raio, 'red'); // menor circulo
        function dispara(evento)
        {
            var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
            var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;
            if(x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10){
                alert('Acertou no alvo, e ganhou 50 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 50;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20)!= (x <= xx + 10 & x >= xx - 10 & y >= yy -10 & y <= yy + 10))
            {
                alert('Acertou mais nao no alvo, e ganhou 15 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 15;
                inicio();
            }
            if((x <= xx + 30 & x >= xx - 30 & y >= yy -30 & y <= yy + 30)!= (x <= xx + 20 & x >= xx - 20 & y >= yy -20 & y <= yy + 20))
            {
                alert('quase errou, e ganhou 5 Pontos');
                pontos = pontos + 5;
                inicio();
            }
        }
 tela.onclick = dispara;
    }
    inicio();
</script>
```